# how to change dropdowns values based on a selection of another dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have my first dropdown with 2 selections: Standard Glass and Tempered glass.
I have another dropdown where the user can select the width of the glass.

My problem: the second dropdown values need to change depending on what kind of glass was selected in the first dropdown.

Look at my code, I have the 2 dropdowns with an id of glassWidthStandard and the other dropdown glassWidthTempered.

Thank you :) here is my code:

```
 <select id="typeOfGlass">
  <option value="15">Standard/Annealed Glass Width</option>
    <option value="20">Tempered Glass Width</option>
</select><br>


Glass Width for Standard:<br>
    <select id="glassWidthStandard">
        <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
    </select>

Glass Width for Tempered:<br>
    <select id="glassWidthTempered">
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: but where is your `jquery` code? what have you tried? Consider adding a jsfiddle.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not quiet clear. As i see there are three dropdowns.

Comment: I do not know where to start, I found this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/fRuhn/) but the parameter to filter is the options, I cannot have the same values for groups for the second dropdown.

Comment: Yes, there are 3 dropdowns, the first dropdown will select which of the 2 other remaining dropdowns should show

Comment: I'll help you out with some pseudo code: on change of `#typeOfGlass`, hide or show the corresponding select.  Now show use your _love for doing websites_ and we'll show you some love in return.

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Ljtgkkaz/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest having just two selects, then changing the 2nd select based on what is selected in the first.

```
$('#typeOfGlass').on('change', function(){
    $('#glassWidth').html('');
    if($('#typeOfGlass').val()==15){
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="19">19</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="20">20</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="21">21</option>');
    }else{
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="6">6</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="7">7</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="8">8</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="9">9</option>');
    }
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6hmpa1ax/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you don't want to dynamically change the DOM you can hide/show the premade markup. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qg0ftfnp/2/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="typeOfGlass">
    <option selected disabled>Please select a glass type</option>
    <option value="15">Standard/Annealed Glass Width</option>
    <option value="20">Tempered Glass Width</option>
</select>
<br />

<div class="standard">
    <label>Glass Width for Standard:</label>
    <select id="glassWidthStandard">
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="tempered">
    <label>Glass Width for Tempered:</label>
    <select id="glassWidthTempered">
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#typeOfGlass').on('change', function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 15 ){
        $('.tempered').hide();
        $('.standard').show();
    } else if( $(this).val() == 20 ){
        $('.standard').hide();
        $('.tempered').show();
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.standard, .tempered {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this code

```
<body  onLoad="fun('')">

<select id="typeOfGlass" onchange="fun(this.value)" >
 <option value=''>select</option>
  <option value="15">Standard/Annealed Glass Width</option>
    <option value="20">Tempered Glass Width</option>
</select><br/><br/>


    <select id="glassWidthStandard">
        <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
    </select>
    <select id="glassWidthTempered">
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>


</body>
<script>
 function fun(val)
 {
  if(val==15)
  {
    $('#glassWidthTempered').hide();
    $('#glassWidthStandard').show();
  }
  else if(val==20)
  {
    $('#glassWidthStandard').hide();
    $('#glassWidthTempered').show();
  }
  else if(val=='')
  {
    $('#glassWidthStandard').hide();
    $('#glassWidthTempered').hide();
  }
 }
</script>
```